# Couldn't erase all rpm packages with using "dnf erase *-.rpm and rpm -e *.rpm"

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, fedora-22

I installed some packages with `rpm -i *.rpm` and `dnf install *.rpm`

But, I couldn't erase these all packages which I install with dnf -i *.rpm, rpm -i *.rpm but, I want to erase these with `rpm -e *.rpm` and `dnf remove *.rpm`

It gave this error:

```
Error: No packages marked for removal.
```

But, I tried install these erasing all packages again with `rpm -i *.rpm` and `dnf install *.rpm`. 
But, it gave this error:

```
package somepackage(s).rpm is already installed"
```

But, I tried again to erase these package again, but, It gave again same error:

```
Error: No packages marked for removal.
```

I want to learn, how can I erase these packages without erasing just one-by-one. I want just to erase these packages immediately by using *.rpm.

I tried install just one package again it finished, and I tried to erase this package and it finished.

I just want to erase all packages just one command as `rpm -i *`

Can you help me where is wrong with command in bash. Maybe I am not right. Can you help me to fix this problem.

Sorry for my bad English.( My native tongue is not English ).
Thanks for your time.

I wish we will live in a better world, like everyone is using open source software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the packages which you just installed, you need the package *names*, not the names of the files.  Usually (not always) you can get this by stripping the ".rpm" suffix from each, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST=
for name in *.rpm
do
    LIST="$LIST $(basename $name .rpm)"
done
sudo dnf remove $LIST
```

Removing packages with `dnf` is preferable to using `rpm` directly, since dependencies are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

For installing you use **file name**. E.g "foo-1.2-x86_64.rpm."
For removing (or quering) you use **package name** E.g. "foo" or "foo-1.2-x86_64". I.e. **without** that ".rpm" suffix.